# Calculating change in an account month to month in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of data that looks like this

| Person | month | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Dec | Blue |
| A | Nov | Blue |
| A | Oct | Red |
| A | Sept | Red |
| B. | Dec | Red |
| B | Nov | Blue |
| B. | Jan | Red |

I am attempting to create a fourth column that is a binary 0 1 depending on if the color changed from Red to blue(0 for no 1 for yes) from the previous month. How can I do this using SQL?
New table should look something like this.

| Person | month | color | Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Dec | Blue | 0 |
| A | Nov | Blue | 1 |
| A | Oct | Red | 0 |
| A | Sept | Red | 0 |
| B | Dec | Red | 0 |
| B | Nov | Blue | 1 |
| B | Jan | Red | 0 |

I have tried some if statements but the problem that I am having is that my code needs to look at the previous months color not just the current one. For example, if November for person A is blue and December for person A is also blue then there is no change from red to blue.

Comment: Exactly what engine are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Etc.

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Is month a varchar like in your example above or datetime? i.e. month #?

Comment: Yes sorry it is in datetime, was just faster to write this way and did not realize the difference at the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
      ,case when lag(color) over(partition by person order by month) <> color and color = 'Blue' then 1 else 0 end as change
from   t
```

| Person | month | color | change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 9 | Red | 0 |
| A | 10 | Red | 0 |
| A | 11 | Blue | 1 |
| A | 12 | Blue | 0 |
| B | 1 | Red | 0 |
| B | 11 | Blue | 1 |
| B | 12 | Red | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7nn_9uEr)

Comment: Exactly what I needed thanks so much. Never even knew about the lag function.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the month is a varchar as in OP's example

Comment: @GRIV in that case he needs to change them into dates because there is no way to order it in a way that makes sense. From his comment I'm guessing that's how he has it in his database and he just didn't put it here.

Comment: Yes sorry it is in datetime, was just faster to write this way and did not realize the difference at the time.

Comment: Ah no worries, I had a solution in the works for the varchar similar to @DannySlor's above. Please post your exact data next time :) I think I'll post it anyways in case someone runs into the varchar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `CTE` to convert the `month` string into `datetime` then `LAG` to compare the previous result:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
  Month(cast(substring("month",0,4)+'1 2016' as datetime)) AS month_converted
  FROM sample_table
  )
SELECT Person, "month", color,
  CASE WHEN 
  LAG(color) OVER(PARTITION BY person ORDER BY month_converted) <> color 
  and color = 'Blue' 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS Change
FROM cte 
ORDER BY Person ASC, month_converted DESC
```

**Result:**

| Person | month | color | change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Dec | Blue | 0 |
| A | Nov | Blue | 1 |
| A | Oct | Red | 0 |
| A | Sept | Red | 0 |
| B | Dec | Red | 0 |
| B | Nov | Blue | 1 |
| B | Jan | Red | 0 |

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7oBSf0jM).

Also, its worth nothing, the column named `month` is a [Reserved Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#:%7E:text=DEALLOCATE-,MONTH,-TRUE) in SQL Server. It is advised to change it to something else that is not reserved.